# How to combine str.replace() expressions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I want to combine all them expressions into one and haven't got a clue how to do it, it needs to remove the end white-space and remove the beginning white-space but shorten white-space between two words to only one (if there's more than one). Thanks

```
var _str = document.contact_form.contact_name.value;
name_str = _str.replace(/\s+/g,' ');
str_name = name_str.replace(/\s+$/g,'');
name = str_name.replace(/^\s+/g,'');
document.contact_form.contact_name.value = name;
```

Comment: It takes all of 60 seconds to test this but I checked SO for the answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can combine the second two into a single regular expression:

```
name = _str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
```

You could also look at jQuery's [trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method.

> Description: Remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

Comment: In which order do they execute?

Answer (score 3):

```
var name = _str.replace(/\s+$|^\s+/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
```

You can use the `|` character in your regular expression to match the sub-expression on either side of it, and you can chain multiple calls to `.replace()`.

By the way, don't forget to declare all of your variables with `var`.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.contact_form.contact_name.value = _str.replace(/\s+/g,' ')..replace(/\s+$/g,'').replace(/^\s+/g,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like it's time to define `function compactify(str)`.  Even if you could cram all of that into one RegEx, the result would be difficult to read and worse to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Chain trim() and replace()

```
var _str = "       This is a      string          ";
name_str = _str.trim().replace(/\s+/g, " ");
console.log(name_str);
```

The `trim()` method removes whitespace from both sides of a string. The trim() method does not change the original string.